With Visual Studio, can I specify Solution Configuration and Solution Platform on the command line?
Looking at the command line arguments to Visual Studio, it should be possible to specify
/ProjectConfig "Debug|x64"


, but it doesn't seem to actually work.
How should :Configuration/Platform: for a solution be specified?;)

so what do you expect the outcome to be, if you run the command and specify a build configuration? also, is the build configuration you specified also contained in the .sln file, and in the project .(*proj) files?

Yes, the solution configuration ("Debug") and solution platform ("x64") is something which is available in the drop-down menu. I want to specify this on the command line, so that when I start Visual Studio, the drop-down menu is set to these values.

so, if you open your .sln file in a text editor, is there a definition for "Debug|x64"? I know by default there are definitons for "Debug|AnyCPU" and "Release|AnyCPU", but do you have Build configurations saved for the x64 platform? Also note that from what i see at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/projectconfig-devenv-exe?view=vs-2022, it doesn't seem like platform configuration is considered/accepted in the /projectconfig option. your platform should be identified by the project build setting for your named build configuration.
